# Create a copy of an existing database and rename it with a Powershell script

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to automate a task in my project as described below using powershell script which i found on stack overflow.

1. Login SQL Server from integrated environment.
2. Create a copy of existing database in the same SQL Server and rename it.

---

```
Import-Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking

$Server = "Servername"

$SQLInstanceName = "SQLInsta\Test01"

$SourceDBName   = "mrl_mpr_2_4_db"

Param(
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$CopyDBName
     )

$Server  = New-Object -TypeName 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server' -ArgumentList $SQLInstanceName

$SourceDB = $Server.Databases[$SourceDBName]


**$CopyDB = New-Object -TypeName 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Database' -  ArgumentList $Server, $CopyDBName**
```

below Error While executing the above highlighted line

> PS SQLSERVER:> $CopyDB = New-Object -TypeName
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Database' -ArgumentList $Server,
>   $CopyDBName
>
> New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s):
>   "SetParent failed for Database 'Test_DB_1_0_DB'. "
>
> At line:1 char:11
>
> - $CopyDB = New-Object -TypeName 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Database' -Ar ...
> - ```
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId :  ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
>   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this script.  It will handle all aspects of copying a database including, checking space on the target drive, checking if the required certificates are present on the target machine, checking the compatibility of the SQL versions.  It will run in 1 line, and will apply all required configurations, such as setting the compatibility level to match the new version, setting the recovery level, optionally copying users and logins, or restoring the original permissions of the target database, etc.

See the Wiki

https://github.com/MikeyMing/powershell-sql/wiki/BackupAndRestore

Please feel free to contribute.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to set domain of your server

```
 $Server = "Domain\Servername"
```

Edit:

Firstly, change

```
$CopyDB = New-Object -TypeName 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Database' -  ArgumentList $Server, $CopyDBName
```

as

```
$CopyDB = New-Object -TypeName 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Database' -ArgumentList $Server, $CopyDBName
```

then follow these steps to debug the issue

```
$Server  = New-Object -TypeName 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server' -ArgumentList cwsql_listener
$Server

Instance Name                   Version    ProductLevel UpdateLevel  HostPlatform HostDistribution
-------------                   -------    ------------ -----------  ------------ ----------------
your-server-name                13.0.5101  SP2          n/a          Windows      n/a


$SourceDB = $Server.Databases[$SourceDBName]
$SourceDB


  Name                 Status           Size Space Avai Recovery Compat. Owner                     Collation
                                                lable  Model     Level
----                 ------           ---- ---------- -------- ------- -----                     ---------
xxxxxxxxxxx          Normal          xx GB     xx  GB Full         100 xxxx\xxxxxx         Turkish_CI_AS


$CopyDB = New-Object -TypeName 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Database' -ArgumentList $Server, "test"
$CopyDB
```

Name                 Status           Size Space Avai Recovery Compat. Owner                     Collation
                                                lable  Model     Level
----                 ------           ---- ---------- -------- ------- -----                     ---------
test                                   xx MB        xx KB                0

Comment: Hello Dervis, Still the same even error after setting the Domain Name.

Comment: HI Dervis, i am really sorry that i am not able to follow you as i ma very new to this. I did change as you mentioned. i receive the empty table with no details as below for CWSQL Listener.                                                                                                              PS SQLSERVER:\> $Server  = New-Object -TypeName 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server' -ArgumentList cwsql_listener
$Server

Instance Name                                                                   
-------------

Comment: Import-Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking
$Server = "NORTHAMERICA\Servername"
$SQLInstanceName = "TEST01"
$SourceDBName = "mrl_mpr_2_4_db"
$Server  = New-Object -TypeName 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server' -ArgumentList cwsql_listener
$Server
$Server  = New-Object -TypeName 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server' -ArgumentList $SQLInstanceName
$SourceDB = $Server.Databases["mrl_mpr_2_4_db"]
$SourceDB
$CopyDB = New-Object -TypeName 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Database'-ArgumentList $Server,"TEST_DB"
$CopyDB.Create()